# Change margin/spacing of footnote in Word

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word-2011

There is some funky formatting issues going on with my footnotes in Word (Mac 2011):

[image]

How do I decrease the gap between the footnote and separator line? This answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/35606/how-can-i-remove-this-large-gap-above-my-footnotes-in-ms-word) doesn't apply to my version of Word, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to "Draft view" and then make sure Footnotes is selected from the View menu as well.

[image: see image 1]

Then select separator from the dropdown panel in the frame that appears at the bottom of the screen.

[image: see image 2]

Then all you do is delete the space! If you turn on hidden character mode, you can see it's a newline symbol causing the error.